# Preimage of zero in concrete abelian category

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an abelian category and $\mathcal{F}$ be a faithful functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathrm{Set}$. For any object $A$ and every arrow $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(A, B)$ we write (identifying) $A = \mathcal{F}(A)$ and $f = \mathcal{F}(f)$.
Suppose further that the zero object $0 \in \operatorname{Obj} \mathcal{C}$ is associated under $\mathcal{F}$ with $\{ 0 \}$, so that for every object $A$ we can say that $0 \in A$.

Usually we think of the kernel of a morphism as $f^{-1}(0)$. Is it the case that if $f \in \operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ and $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = 0$, then there exists $y \in K$ such that $g(y) = x$ where $g \in \operatorname{Hom}(K, A)$ is the kernel of $f$.

Comment: If you want a *unique* $y\in K$ such that $g(y)=x$, then it's the same as asking whether the forgetful functor preserves kernels, which is not always true (although for a lot of practical cases it is).